# Why git format-patch silently fails?

Tags: git, format-patch

I am issuing these:

```
git format-patch 2f3e744 2f3e744^
```

or

```
git format-patch 2f3e744..3e853
```

In the latter, 3e853 is a commit earlier than 2f3e744.

Neither command resulted in some change (not the result I was expecting).

My goal is to make a patch based on changes from revision 3e853.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're subject is actually wrong.  You're command line is not providing that, it's providing `^2f3e744 3e853`, which excludes your commit.  The proper way to write this is `git format-patch 3e853..2f3e744`.  You could also do:

- `git format-patch -1 3e853` - Which means take 1 commit starting at 3e853.
- `git format-patch 3e853 '^3e853^'` - Which means taken the set the leads up to 3e853, and subtract out everything before it.  Note the quotes.  Some shells will try to interpret the carets (^), so you may need them.

The [`git rev-list`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) docs are a good resource for this information.

**Update**: You're title changed, it's the first example now.  And it may not be producing anything because your history is short.  I'd expect the first command to emit a patch for everything up to 2f3e744.